# IPC Connect to Ethereum node running on docker

Tags: ipc

I am creating a Ruby client to connect to Ethereum node inside a docker container. So far,

I was able to run ethereum-go inside docker container Then I bash into docker container & able to connect my ruby client using ipc file location `.ethereum/rinkeby/geth.ipc`

But is there a way I can connect to that docker ethereum node from another container? or else from host computer? Because I want to run my Ruby client in another container

Comment: Docker support mapping a file in the container to a file in the host with the `--volume` option. I've never tried it with a pipe/unix socket.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with RUBY. I am trying same in GoLang though.

I hope my work can help you get started.
I created this `docker-compose.yml`.
I run the client by `docker-compose up`.

```
version: '2'

services:
  etherum-client:
      image: ethereum/client-go:stable
      ports:
          - "30303:30303"
          - "8545:8545"
      volumes:
          - ./share/ethereum/:/root/.ethereum/
      command: --rinkeby --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --fast
```

As the volume is shared, you get the `geth.ipc` file created in your MAC also.

**ALSO** you can SH into the docker client by simple command
`docker exec -it <container name> sh`

Inside shell I can then connect to geth using command
`geth attach ipc:/root/.ethereum/rinkeby/geth.ipc`

Hope it helps.

Comment: i can connect via IPC in the container `docker exec -ti appetissimo-ethereum geth attach ipc:` but i can't connect from host (ipc path is correct)